Density of Pisot polynomials
Recall that a Pisot polynomial $P=x^n+ a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\ldots a_1$ has integer coefficients, a real root $x_1>1$  and all other roots $|x_i|<1$ for $1\leq i \leq n$.  One key result is that $\{(x_1)^k\}$, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of x, approaches 0 rapidly as $k\rightarrow \infty$. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number)
What is the probability that a randomly chosen integral polynomial is Pisot?
To formalize this one might consider the set of all integers with absolute value less than $M$ and then compute the probability as $M\rightarrow \infty$, if the limit exists.
Numerically, for n=2 the probability is about $p\approx 0.25$, for n=3 we get $p\approx 0.21$ and for n=10 we get $p\approx 0.006$.  The proof for n=2 is straightforward but seems to get messy for larger n.
(As an aside: are there any proofs of the convergence to integer values that don't use Newton's identities? i.e. is there a "fundamental" reason for convergence?)

$\sum x_i^n$ is always an integer (as every symmetric polynomial in $x_i$'s with integer coefficients), why is not this considered fundamental?

I don't quite get the "formalization". How do you relate the integers with absolute value less than $M$, to the polynomials?

@GerryMyerson I mean that the coefficients of the polynomial are randomly chosen from [-M,M].

@FedorPetrov This is really a taste issue. First, I'm just wondering if there is a proof that doesn't use that identity. Second, while I know that the proof of the identity is simple, I don't have any "intuitive" feel why it is true.  Is there some intuition behind it?

We do not need a specific identity, we need only the general fact that every symmetric polynomial is a polynomial of the elementary symmetrics (with coefficients in the same ring). This is less or more clear by lexicographic induction

It is not so bad to show that for each fixed $n$ the probability that $P$ is Pisot converges to the probability that the random polynomial $f_{n-1}(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} U_k z^k$ has all of its $n - 1$ roots in the unit disk where $U_k$ are independent uniform random variables between $[-1,1]$.  Here's a quick sketch of that.

Write $f_{n-1,M}$ to be the random polynomial $f_{n-1,M}(z) = \sum_{k =0}^{n-1} a_k z^k$ where $a_k$ is a uniform integer in $[-M,M]$.  Note then that $P = f_{n-1,M}(z) + z^n$.

As $M \to \infty$, the minimum of $|f_{n-1,M}(z)|$ on the unit circle tends to infinity in probability and so by Rouche's theorem we have that $f_{n-1,M}$ and $P$ have the same number of roots in the unit disk with probability tending to $1$.

Note that as long as $|a_{n-1}|$ is not too small (e.g. we can assume it is at least, say, $M/\log M$ with high probability) then we have that there is a real root of $P$ near $-a_{n-1}$ (this can be seen by observing there is a sign change nearby that point).

Combining the previous two bullet points show that there is an event that holds with high probability on which we have that $P$ is a Pisot polynomial if and only if $f_{n-1,M}$ has all of its roots in the unit disk.

As $M \to \infty$, the probability that $f_{n-1,M}$ has all its roots in the unit disk converges to the probability that $f_{n-1}$ has all its roots in the unit disk.  There are many ways to see this, but one way to see it is to couple the two together via setting the random variables $a_j$ to be $M U_j$ rounded to the nearest integer and then using Hurwitz's theorem to assert that $f_{n-1}$ and $f_{n-1,M}/M$ have the same number of roots in the unit disk as $M \to \infty$.


So if we let $p_{n}$ be the probability that $f_{n}$ has all of its roots in the unit disk, it is also interesting to ask how $p_n$ behaves as $n \to\infty$.  A quick lower bound is $p_n \geq 2^{-n} / n!$ since if the coefficients satisfy $0 \leq a_0 \leq a_1 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$ then all roots lie in the unit disk (this is called the Enestrom-Kakeya Theorem).  It is not obvious to me how quickly $p_n$ should decay to $0$. This seems like it could be an interesting question too.

Interesting, I know there are results for random polynomials   with Real coefficients, but are there results for integral coefficients?

@ericf Yes there are.  I also realized that I didn't define $U_k$, which is a uniform random variable in the interval $[-1,1]$, so the discrete nature of the problem comes out in the limit.
